# append string to each element in string array in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

How can I append a string to each element from a string array in typescript
I have an array like `const original = ['a', 'b', 'c']` I want to make it as `const original_string = ['i am key a', 'i am key b', 'i am key c']` how can I do that? maybe something like `const original_string = original.map(() => ${'i am key'})`?
I have following but it does not work

```
const original_string = original.forEach((item)=> (`i am key ${item}`));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const original = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const original_string = original.map(item => `i am key ${item}`)
console.log({original, original_string});
```

You want to use `map` which will put the value in the array for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
const original = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const original_string : any = [];

original.map((a) => {
  original_string.push("Key " + a);
});

console.log(original_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function to create a new array out of existing array, in this case you want to create `original_string` out of `original` array.

For eg. You can do this.

```
const original = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const original_string: string[] = original.map((key: string) => {
   return `I'm key ${key}`;
});

console.log(original_string);
```